# Order by text field with an index - using filesort

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to order by and use an index but it seems to still be using filesort

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `teachers` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`lastName` tinytext NOT NULL,
KEY `lastName` (lastName(10))
)
```

Query

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT name,lastName FROM teachers ORDER BY lastName DESC;
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | teachers | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1546 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
```

Comment: Excerpt: Filesort is used when `You index only a prefix of a column named in the ORDER BY clause. In this case, the index cannot be used to fully resolve the sort order. For example, if you have a CHAR(20) column, but index only the first 10 bytes, the index cannot distinguish values past the 10th byte and a filesort will be needed.`

Comment: I redid the index. I original tried it without the prefix and forgot to remove it.

Comment: Is it a valid create statement?

Comment: It should be, I type it out so it might have a typo.

Comment: Are you expecting us to find typos?

Comment: I corrected it however I'm expecting the create to be unnecessary for someone to answer the question.

Comment: Any particular reason for using `tinytext` for `lastname`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a covering index `last name, name`

```
CREATE TABLE `teachers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `last_first` (`lastName`,`name`)
)
```

Now that query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `name`, lastName FROM teachers ORDER BY lastName DESC;
```

Produces the following result

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | teachers | index | NULL          | last_first | 269     | NULL |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in key definition: **KEY `lastName` (lastName(10))**

Especially that you have defined a KEY length here

You index **only a prefix of a column** named in the ORDER BY clause. In this case, the index cannot be used to fully resolve the sort order. For example, if you have a CHAR(20) column, but index only the first 10 bytes, the index cannot distinguish values past the 10th byte and a **filesort will be needed**.

[Proof link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)

You can write **KEY `lastName` (lastName)** and it will work as you need.